# Why does my media query not trigger on iPhone?

Tags: html, iphone, css

I am trying to get a media query to activate on iPhone screens, but it isn't triggering on my iPhone 5. My CSS is:

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
.left-col-bio { width: 100%; }
.sidebar-bio { width: 100%; } 
.left-col-lab { width: 100%; }
.sidebar-lab { width: 100%; } 
}
```

This should trigger on an iPhone 5, shouldn't it? Since the iPhone's width is 320 virtual pixels, correct? In the related questions I've looked at, people often suggest including

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1">
```

but I already have that in place. I only have an iPhone 5 to test this on, so I'm not sure if it displays correctly on a non-retina screen, and if therein lies the problem. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: `@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) { }`

Answer (score 1):

iPhone5

```
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) {  
}  
or  
@media screen and (device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){  
}
```

Blackberry Torch

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {   
}
```

Samsung S3

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {  
}
```

Google Nexus 7

```
@media screen and (device-width: 600px) and (device-height: 905px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.331) and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.332) {  
}
```

iPad Mini

```
@media screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {  
}
```

iPad 3

```
@media (max-device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait) {   
}
```

Galaxy Tab 10.1

```
@media (max-device-width: 800px) and (orientation: portrait) {   
}
```

Comment: I tried both variations of what you suggested for iPhone 5, and neither worked for me. I'm not necessarily setting up media queries around device resolutions, moreso around just what makes sense content-wise. With what i suggested originally,

     @media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {}

shouldn't this work for any width below 550px? If I set that number to 775px for example, it WILL trigger on my iPhone.

Comment: iPhone is 640px*1186px,so your code "@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {} " can not trigger in iPhone 5

Comment: I've tried (max-width: 640px) {} as well actually. It doesn't trigger... besides, I thought that in terms of virtual pixels, the width of the iPhone 5 is considered the same as non-Retina iPhones (320px)?

Comment: this code:"-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2" means even though iphone5 is 640px width,but it has for pixel point to drawing one point,so the actual width you see is 320px

Comment: This makes sense to me, but it still didn't work for me. This is what I wrote:
    @media screen and (device-width: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){ }

Comment: iphone5's device-width is 320px,and max-width is 640px

Comment: I have tried a ton of variations on what you've been telling me, but nothing is working. I can't explain it. Like I said, when I set the max-width to 775px, it looks correct on my iPhone. But I don't want to really use that media query because on a desktop browser, having the media query trigger at that width looks odd. Is there anything I could be missing here? Thanks.

Comment: try this"@media screen and (max-width: 640px){} ",I just test at my iphone 4s

Comment: I have tried that, and I have no luck. I really appreciate you trying to help me... maybe you could look at my code for me? Here is the page: http://kerfootlab.com/bio.html. That layout readjusts based on the viewport, and it looks correct on a computer browser, but not on my iPhone for some reason. The media queries are at the bottom of the CSS file.